# I want to calculate time code block in trigger

Tags: postgresql, time, triggers, execution

I create a trigger in Postgresql. This trigger executes some update statements. I want to calculate the time how much time to do these statements. An example I have two update statements and I do not know these statements execution time. The first updates execution time what is it and also second updates execution time what is it? 
{

```
create or replace
function public.insert_sth() returns trigger language plpgsql as $function$
declare time1 timestamp without time zone;
declare time2 timestamp without time zone;
declare timediff bigint;
begin
time1:=current_timestamp;--now();
RAISE NOTICE 'Calling update healthy time1 %', time1;   
if exists(
    select 1
from
    basetable
where
    id= NEW.id) then update
    basetable
set
    previous_id= this_id
where
    id= NEW.id;

update
    basetable
set
    this_id= NEW.id
where
    id= NEW.id;

update
    basetable
set
    healthy_id= (
        select id
    from
        sometable
    where
        connectionresult = 0
        or connectionresult = 2
        and sometable.id= NEW.id
    order by
        sometable.actiontime desc
    limit 1)
where
    id= new.id;
time2:=current_timestamp;--now();
timediff:= (EXTRACT('epoch' from time2) - EXTRACT('epoch' from time1)) * 1000;

RAISE NOTICE 'Calling update healthy check %', timediff;

RAISE NOTICE 'Calling update healthy time2 %', time2;
return new;

else insert
    into
        bastable(id,
        this_id)
    values(NEW.id,
    NEW.id);

return new;

end if;

end;

$function$ ;
```

}

But the output is :

- 00000: Calling update healthy time1 2019-07-18 17:00:08.085
- 00000:   Calling update healthy check 0
- 00000: Calling update healthy time2 2019-07-18 17:00:08.085

this is impossible. The update execution should not be 0 ms. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `current_timestamp`. It is same for the whole transaction.

Use **`clock_timestamp`** instead

It will reflect the clock time.

[**DIfference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()**](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/207-difference-between-current_timestamp-and-clock_timestamp-and-how-to-exploit-them.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I can't believe from where the word session came :-)